# How to get Angular X-editable field to work with no buttons option (buttons=no)?

Tags: angularjs, x-editable, clicktoedit

I would like to use the angular x-editable directive to work with a text field per the following

(a) I don't want to display buttons. I tried the buttons=no option but it does not seem to work with input of type text.

[See the fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/jarnal/ft8gt/1/)

(b) I want the underlying ng-model property to update immediately with each keystroke , without waiting for the user to focus out of the input. (as is default behavior with vanilla angular, eg. `<input type=text  ng-model="somepropertyname" />`

How can one achieve (a) and (b) with angular x-editable? [link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jarnal/ft8gt/1/)

Answer (score 10):

Answer to 1(a) is to add the blur="submit" attribute (in addition to buttons="no")